# Why does SBT libraryDependencies %% truncate scalaVersion?

Tags: scala, sbt

In my build.sbt I have the lines

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-M6"

libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "com.typesafe" %% "slick" % "0.11.0",
    "org.slf4j" %% "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

running `sbt update` shows an unresolved dependency exception.  When I look at the URL sbt is trying to retrieve for the library, I see it's looking for `com.typesafe$slick_2.10;0.11.0`.

Why isn't the full `ScalaVersion` appended?  Is there an option I can use to cause it to use the entire version instead of the truncated one?

Comment: See the very last part of https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Resolvers

Comment: Apologies, I'm not seeing anything that clearly indicates how to rectify including the full scalaVersion .  I'm assuming you're saying I could correct this by setting a new pattern for ivy to resolve with?  Judging by https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies %% should cause the scalaVersion to be appended to the artifactID out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work starting with sbt `0.12`. See [Cross-building](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build) at sbt wiki.

```
"com.typesafe" % "slick" % "0.11.0" cross CrossVersion.full
```