# sbt disagreeing with library about scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use scala-time with scala 2.10, and have found that it doesn't work with sbt correctly.

given something like

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-time" % "0.7"
```

sbt will happily try to resolve http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaj/scalaj-time_2.10/0.7/scalaj-time_2.10-0.7.pom.

Unfortunately, scalaj-time is publised with full scala versions as can be seen at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaj/.

It can be resolved with

```
 libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-time_2.10.2" % "0.7"
```

but I'm wanting to know if this is a change in sbt behaviour, a bug in scala-time's build or if there's a way to configure sbt to pass the 3-part version instead of 2-part.

Comment: `CrossVersion.full` ftw. possible duplicate of [Why does SBT libraryDependencies %% truncate scalaVersion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631948/why-does-sbt-librarydependencies-truncate-scalaversion)

Comment: Seems to me like a bug in scala-time's build

Answer (score 3):

As Seth noted [jorgeortiz85/scala-time](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time) likely was published using sbt that predates binary cross versioning convention that was introduced in sbt 0.12. You could do:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-time_2.10.2" % "0.7"
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-time" % "0.7" cross CrossVersion.full
```

But then you'd be stuck with using 2.10.2 while Scala 2.10.4 is already out.

There's a similar Joda time wrapper named [nscala-time/nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) that seems more actively maintained. Last updated 3 days ago and Scala 2.11.0 is supported already, so that could also be your option.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.0.0"
```

Comment: "There's a similar Joda time wrapper named nscala-time/nscala-time that seems more actively maintained". Yeah - I've raised https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time/issues/56 about that mess. A non-forked "fork" that does not contribute to the network. As you can see in the scala-time network (https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/network), you can get 2.11 support as well. To be clear, I would use nscala-time *if* it could become a correctly forked successor so I could compare changes.